# dict_values to string in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I simply want to convert an object that looks like this:

```
dict_values(['baf0242b-d7fc-49d7-aada-220344969fb6'])
```

That I got from doing this:

```
dictionary.values()
```

To a simple string: `'baf0242b-d7fc-49d7-aada-220344969fb6'`

How can I?

Comment: What should `dict_values(['a', 'b'])` become? "a,b"? "ab"? Something else?

Comment: `dict_values` is a kind of `view`. You can get a list of the things in it by doing `list(your_object)`

Comment: If you want the value for a particular key, why not just use the dict as intended? `dict['key']` will return the value of that key rather than using `.values()`, converting it to a list, then indexing into it anyway

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Say you have a dictionary:

```
d = {'key': 'baf0242b-d7fc-49d7-aada-220344969fb6'}
```

The result you see is from running the following:

```
d.values()
```

To get what you want, convert it to a list and get the first item on it:

```
d = {'key': 'baf0242b-d7fc-49d7-aada-220344969fb6'}
result = list(d.values())[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

`list(your_dict.values())[0]`

As @rdas mentioned, `dict_values` is a `view` in Python 3+, and the first index will return your string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the first value, or the only value in your case. This might be a bit more memory efficient:

```
next(iter(d.values())))
```